# Modal box of bootstrap right:0 not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal box of bootstrap; I want it to be stuck to the right side of the screen; I tried the follwoing but when I re-size the window it does not work :( could you please help me in this regard!

```
<div id='test'>
    <div id="add_pixel" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>

#add_pixel{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

but it does not go to the right side of the screen! It is worth mentioning that my css file gets called after bootstrap css files!

But the following code works fine:

```
<div id="id1">
    <div id='id2'>

    </div>
</div>

#id1{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 400px;
}

#id2{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;        
}
```

I could not figure out why it is not working with modal box of bootstrap, whereas it working fine with regular DIVs !

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Only way i found how to do it, is by modifying bootstrap.css directly.

Find the rule for .modal and remove left:0

Here is an example from the [bootstrap3 livedemo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) with left:0 disabled in firefox.

As far as I know it's not possible to overwrite a css rule to nothing.

[image: Try it out by yourself]

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of issues with this as well, however this following style worked to fit a boarder around the whole modal panel.

```
#clams-modal{
    position:fixed;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:auto;
    z-index:100001;
    left:22px;
    right:22px;
    top:22px;
    bottom:22px ;
}
```

Maybe in your case try something like

```
#add_pixel{
    position:fixed;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:auto;
    z-index:100001;
    left:20%;
    right:0px;
    top:22px;
    bottom:22px ;
}
```

The width being set to auto seemed to be the key factor in making the right fix work.